# Redis expire and increment

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a scenario where, i want to implement a caching mechanism with redis. To go into further detail

First i check for the specific key using **client.get()** and if the value doesn't exists. I need to make a call to a web service, which returns a value and is stored as the child of the key. Then i use **client.set()** to set this key into redis. Now this key needs to expire if it has been set for more than 24hours, how can i do this?

Here is an example of the key-value would look like in redis

```
parentValue:{
    child1:{
        serviceVal: "serviceVal",
        counter: 0
    },

    child2:{...},
    child3:{...}
    .... 
}
```

Now similarly when the initial **client.get()**, is performed and if the value exists and this specific key hasn't expired. I want to increment the **counter** in the object and update this specific key in redis. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

[`SET` with `NX` and `EX`](http://redis.io/commands/SET#options) options is your easiest solution. See an example on a module I'm working on [here](https://github.com/Salakar/redibox/blob/master/src/modules/cache/index.js#L128).

`EX` accepts seconds, so you'll want `86400` seconds for 24 hours.

But for incrementing and expiring you'd probably be best using a redis lua script, something like:

```
--[[
  key 1 -> key name
  arg 1 -> expires in seconds
  arg 2 -> incr by value
]]

-- Key exists so increment it
if redis.call('exists',KEYS[1]) > 0 then
  redis.call('incrby',KEYS[1],tonumber(ARGV[2]))
  return 0
else
  -- key doesn't exist so create with an expiry and the incr amount
  redis.call('setex',KEYS[1],tonumber(ARGV[1]),tonumber(ARGV[2]))
  return 1
end
```

Then you just have to call the script with the key, expiry time and how much to increment by.